# AsyncContext infinite thread termination

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, servlet-3.0

I'm a bit confused how servlet container terminates AsyncContext in application undeployment phase or simply timeout. For example application developer has following code snippet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = "/myServlet", asyncSupported = true)
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyServlet.class);

    @Override  
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync();
        asyncContext.start(new Runnable() {  
            @Override  
            public void run() {  
                log.debug("Start of Task");  

                try {
                    while(true) {
                        response.getWriter().println("random text");
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    log.warn("Async processing exception: " + e.getMessage);
                }
                asyncContext.complete();  

                log.debug("End of Task");  
            }  
        });
    }  
}
```

Here is AsyncContext starts runnable that never ends or until some exception will be thrown in a while loop. So the question is **how container will terminate the thread that is running such infinite runnable**. The only idea that comes in mind is `thread.stop();` but it's deprecated. I almost sure that container doesn't invoke `thread.interrupt();` because it doesn't guarantee thread interruption referencing to javadoc and here developer set up condition while-true instead of while-not-interrupted thus not responsible for such case.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: why container should terminate such a runnable ( if its deliberately using infinite while loop )?

Comment: @SabirKhan what if administrator decided to undeploy application from sevlet container using CLI lib/web UI or whatever. Leave thread running?

Comment: You can override [destroy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#destroy()) method and finish your objects the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web container can't do anything to force shutdown a thread if the the application developer has intentionally made it loop infinitely.

Fortunately, there are several mechanisms available to an application programmer to ensure that an `AsyncContext` doesn't run infinitely.  Some ideas of the top of my head are:

- Setting a timeout for the request via `AsyncContext.setTimeout(long)`
- Overriding the Servlet `destory()` method and calling `AsyncContext.complte()` which will invoke `AsyncListener.onComplete(AsyncEvent)` on each listener.  You could then attach a listener that stops the process, after adding the listener using `AsyncContext.addListener(AsyncListener)`.
- Storing a reference to the thread manually in the servlet class and stopping it in the Servlet `destory()`method.

The main idea is that if you are going to write a Thread that will loop indefinitely (and you care about quiescing threads on shutdown) you are going to need to write some code to ensure your Thread gets stopped properly.

There is a *chance* that the thread used by `AsyncContext.start(Runnable)` is from a managed thread pool:

> `AsyncContext.start(Runnable)`: Causes the container to dispatch a thread, possibly from a managed thread pool, to run the specified Runnable.

However, since the spec is not firm on this you would need to manually investigate how your Java EE implementation interpreted this bit to see if it uses a managed thread or not.  If it does, your thread may be stopped automatically for you when the app server stops.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestions. I think you answered to my main question. Correct me if I am wrong - it is application developer fully responsible for a thread termination thereby responsible for prevention from memory leaks (using any of three options you describe above).

Comment: Yes, if you have resources that are not managed by a container (i.e. a non-managed thread created by `AsyncContext.start(Runnable)`) then you will need to clean up manually.